# Concat Two DataTime Field in EntityDataSource

Tags: casting, entitydatasource, entity-sql

I have two fields with Edm.DateTime type. How can I get just Time in h:mm format and concat them in CommandText of EntityDataSource:
"01/02/2013 3:15 AM and 01/02/2013 4:15 AM" should be  "15:15-16:15"
I found cast for concat, Is it right solution:

```
CommandText="SELECT  CAST([DoctorAppointment].[Start] AS System.String) + '--'+ CAST([DoctorAppointment].[End] AS System.String) 
         as Name FROM  DatabaseEntities.DoctorAppointments as DoctorAppointment"
```

Comment: I solved problem right now by this but I am not sure:
             
              CAST(Hour(CAST([DoctorAppointment].[Start] AS System.DateTime))AS System.String)+':'+ CAST(Minute(CAST([DoctorAppointment].[Start] AS System.DateTime)) AS System.String)
+ '-' + CAST(Hour(CAST([DoctorAppointment].[End] AS System.DateTime)) AS System.String)+':'+ CAST(Minute(CAST([DoctorAppointment].[End] AS System.DateTime)) AS System.String)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select="String.Format(it.[interview_start_date], 'dd/ MM/ YYYY') as Display,
```

This works for me.